# Php gearman file upload

Tags: php, gearman

Is it possible upload a file using gearman ?
Bye.

Comment: I dont see why not. Could you be more specific on what sort of problem you are having?

Comment: I'm looking for a little example just an hint. The main problem is I don't find the way to pass the $job->workload() to the worker may be serialize($_FILE) ?

Answer (score 3):

Use standard php to upload the file. Read the bytes of the file into a variable and  pass to the server.

> A client has some form of blob data
>   and wants to farm out the processing
>   of the data to the cloud. To do so, it
>   makes a connection to the Server and
>   requests that the server perform some
>   function on that data.

[Read the docs.](http://gearman.org/index.php?id=gearman_php_extension)

Answer (score 0):

This reads the file using file_get_contents, it is passed on to the do() method of GearmanClient. There's no need to "upload" the content, it will be transmitted to gearman, and further to the worker.

client.php

```
<?php
$client= new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
print_r(unserialize($client->do("wordcount", file_get_contents('filename.txt'))));
```

worker.php

```
<?php
$worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("wordcount", "worker_function");
while ($worker->work());

function worker_function($job)
{
  return serialize(array_count_values(str_word_count($job->workload(),1)));
}
```